# Is there a way to use the PopUp control on a Panorama page in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 Panorama application. On one of the pages I would like to show a PopUp once the user clicks a button. The PopUp has a ListBox on it.

The issue is the ListBox items are not matching up to the PopUp's location, they seem to be matched to the top of the Panorama page or the top of the device screen. If I scroll way down on the list I can finally see the text items, but as soon as I let go they spring back up into the top of the list off screen.

It's really straight forward code I'm testing this out with. Simple PopUp inside simple panorama.

```
        <Popup x:Name="ContextMenuPopup" Height="250" Width="300" Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsOpen="True">
            <ListBox Background="White">
                <ListBoxItem Content="Menu 1"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Menu 2"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Menu 3"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Menu 4"/>
            </ListBox>
        </Popup>
```

Pretty sure this is a bug, anyone know of way to work around it?

Comment: where is your xaml in resoect of the Panorama?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a bug. See the convoluted workaround that Jeff Wilcox (Microsoft Developer) posted here:

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/03/acb-in-pivot/